# Getting a NameError for a variable I have defined in my Class

Tags: python, class, nameerror

I am trying to run some code that allows me to either call the name Student or Programmer from the class I called Master_programmer. Here is the code I used.

```
class Master_programmer:

    capabilities = []
    student = "SoloLearn Student"
    programmer = "Programmer"

    def Student(self): 
        return 'SoloLearn Student'


    def Programmer(self): 
        return 'Programmer'

    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def add_capabilities(self, capability):
        self.capabilities.append(capability)


m1 = Master_programmer(programmer)
print(m1.Student, m1.Programmer)

a.add_capabilities('Stay Inspired')
b.add_capabilities('Find Clients')
b.capability
```

After running the above code, I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Playground/file0.py", line 21, in <module>
    m1 = Master_programmer(programmer)
NameError: name 'programmer' is not defined
```

Now, my question is, how do I get my code to deliver the expected results? e.g when I request for the Name 'programmer' to be called up,  I expect it to bring up Programmer and then allow me to add capabilities to the programmer like "Find Clients". And for Student it must be "Stay Inspired".

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't produce that error

Comment: You're right, allow me to update it.

Comment: I've updated the code. Any ideas?

Comment: The variable `programmer` doesn't exist until after you've instantiated the object, but you're trying to pass it into the `init` when you create the object

Comment: You aren't actually calling the methods: `m1.Student()`, etc. Also, see PEP-8 for Python naming conventions. `Master_Programmer` should be `MasterProgrammer`, with methods named `student` and `programmer`.

Comment: It's also not clear why you have class attributes `student` and `programmer` and methods that appear to just return their values.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the below code and its comments will answer your question.

```
class Master_programmer:
    STATIC_VARIABLE_ONE_FOR_EVERY_INSTANCES = 'This is Static Var'
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.capabilities = []
        self.student = "SoloLearn Student"
        self.programmer = "Programmer"

    def get_student(self): 
        return self.student

    def get_programmer(self): 
        return self.programmer

    def add_capabilities(self, capability):
        self.capabilities.append(capability)

# Create instance for your class and name it coder (or whatever you like)
coder = Master_programmer('Replace me with student name')

# to call coder object's variable 
# you need to call it by object name just like below
print('capabilities: ', coder.capabilities)
print(coder.programmer)
print(coder.student)
coder.add_capabilities('Stay Inspired')
coder.add_capabilities('Find Clients')
print(coder.get_student())
print(coder.get_programmer())
print('capabilities: ', coder.capabilities)
print()

# you can invoke Static variables usign directly class name
# you can invoke usign instance name as well but, it is not convention
print(Master_programmer.STATIC_VARIABLE_ONE_FOR_EVERY_INSTANCES)
print()

# if you change Static member, it will get change for all of your instances
coder_2 = Master_programmer('Replace me with student name')
Master_programmer.STATIC_VARIABLE_ONE_FOR_EVERY_INSTANCES = 'changed'
print()

# print static var using both ways
print(Master_programmer.STATIC_VARIABLE_ONE_FOR_EVERY_INSTANCES)
print(coder.STATIC_VARIABLE_ONE_FOR_EVERY_INSTANCES)
print(coder_2.STATIC_VARIABLE_ONE_FOR_EVERY_INSTANCES)
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but don't use getters. They serve no purpose

Answer (score 0):

```py
m1 = Master_programmer(programmer)
print(m1.Student, m1.Programmer)
```

Is calling the variable `programmer` if you wan to refer to  `programmer = "Programmer"` in the `Master_programmer` class you need to use `Master_programmer.programmer` instead.

Though your code will later crash if you don't initialse `a` and `b` too since you need to define them too like *normal* variables e.g. `a = Master_programmer("EEZi")` to call them and/ or work with them

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your answers. Here is the final code that I went with and it works really well. Many Thanks to you.

```
class Master_programmer:
    STATIC_VARIABLE_ONE_FOR_EVERY_INSTANCES = 'This is Static Var'
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name
        self.capabilities = []
        self.student = "SoloLearn Student"
        self.programmer = "Programmer"

    def get_student(self): 
        return self.student


    def get_programmer(self): 
        return self.programmer


    def add_capabilities(self, capability):
        self.capabilities.append(capability)




coder = Master_programmer('EEZi')


coder.add_capabilities('Stay Inspired!')
coder.add_capabilities('Find Clients')

a = coder.get_student()
b = coder.get_programmer()
capabilities = coder.capabilities


for i in range(0,1):
    print(a)
    print("Listen here, just", coder.capabilities[0], "\n")
    print(b)
    print("Hustle hard and", coder.capabilities[1])
```